# Is this legit to keep a default value and avoid exception?

Tags: java

```
    private int getScreenWidth(){
        int width;
        try{
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            width = screenSize.width >= 1024 ? screenSize.width : 1024;
        }catch(HeadlessException e){
            logger.write("couldnt get screen width" + e);
            width = 1024;
        }
        return width;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no. The [HeadlessException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) gets

> thrown when code that is dependent on
>   a keyboard, display, or mouse is
>   called in an environment that does not
>   support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

There is no point in forcing a screen size inside an environment that does **not** have a screen.

In this case, the application should quit instead of reverting to a default value.

Comment: thanks :) The only thing common about my common sence is my lack of it

Comment: Just cuz im on a roll; the exception will only be thrown if the getScreenSize() method returns exception, nothing about keyboards and mice will be thrown right?

Comment: @slex: Right - as long as the `try` block is about calling `getScreenSize()`.